# Building queries linked by OR

Tags: python, ponyorm

I'm trying to query a table using a chain of OR statements.  In practice, I would like to do a query like:

```
... 
 WHERE A.name = ? or A.name = ? or A.name = ? ...
```

BUT the possible values are stored in a list, I don't know how long it is.  So I might end up writing a Pony query like this:

```
# names is my list, it contains str
select(tag for tag in Tag if any(tag.name == name for name in names))
```

This doesn't work, Pony complains I'm trying to iterate over something other than an entity or query (correct!).  I could try to play with the filter method and build the query little by little, like this:

```
names = ["first", "second", "third"] 
query = select(tag for tag in Tag) 
for name in names: 
    query = query.filter(tag for tag in query if tag.name == name)
```

But this doesn't work, as it results in a chain of AND statements, not OR statements, and there doesn't seem a way to build OR queries.

> In this simplistic example, of course, I could use the Python `in` keyword, but this would fail with a more complicated query, like this:

```
select(tag for tag in Tag if any(tag.name.startswith(name) for name in names))
```

Is there something obvious (or less obvious) I missed?

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps the [select_by_sql](https://docs.ponyorm.org/queries.html#using-the-select-by-sql-and-get-by-sql-methods) method helps you

Comment: It could. But I'd like to use Python whenever possible. The idea of using an ORM is, for me, to try to avoid the gruesome SQL work, and I know a lot of ORMs can do that.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `if tag.name in names`?